# first catch catches any type

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, mingw, catch-block

this bit of code is driving me nuts:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "foo";
    try
    {
        throw test;
    }
    catch (const int &x)
    {
        std::cout << "int " << x << "\n";
    }
    catch (const double &x)
    {
        std::cout << "double " << x  << "\n";
    } 
    catch (const std::string &x)
    {
        std::cout << "string " << x  << "\n";
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing crazy here. But the output ...

```
int 7675456
```

I tried it on my linux VM, on GDB online and repl-it and it's working fine. I mean I have what I expect:

```
string foo
```

I never post on here because I always find a solution. But this time, It looks that I can't figure out a correct way to ask google and I'm just lost. Anybody got a clue?

Windows 10 and I use MinGW

Comment: On what system do you get the unexpected output?

Comment: No repro with any of the usual three compilers.

Comment: Can't reproduce, can you give details about your compiler and platform?

Comment: Windows 10. Sorry Baum mit Augen, I don't understand what you mean with "repro".

Comment: @usePtr It's short for "could not reproduce". I'm a lazy typer. :) Anyways, you still have to tell us what compiler you used.

Comment: Sorry, I should have put those straight away in the main post. I use MinGW.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I cannot test that myself as I'm not on windows, but that would clearly be a bug in said compiler.

Comment: That's just a case test that I made up, but it's always like that. Whatever I do, the first catch gonna catch any type. BTW thanks. Reinstalling MinGW could solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without an easy repro case, but try this:
Move the

> catch (const std::string &x)

to be BEFORE the catch for int.

What I suspect may be happening is that since it can somehow the string can be cast to an int, it is trying to do so. While this may not be a complete answer, at least you are a step closer to understanding what is going on, and now you have a workaround.

It is hard to debug something like this remotely, but if nothing else, it is a good exercise in critical logic and debugging approaches.

Comment: If I do that, it's working fine. The issue is that if I put that bloc there, it will catch any types too :D

Comment: Ok, I tried the changing compiler solution. I just renamed my MinGW folder and used Perl's C compiler (I just discovered that it had one). It's working fine. So I guess I could just download a fresh copy of MinGW 64 and everything gonna be alright.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1269290
may be (related to) the root cause.

Comment: Yeah, so somehow your compiler was indeed casting that string & into an int.  I'd call that "understandable, but definitely not expected" behavior.